# JSON AND TABLEVIEW DRILL DOWN

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitableview

I have three uitableviews with navigational controller. Each tableview is populated by arrays through JSON. In mySQL table i have categories, then items such as City and then more details about the city. A user can be able to select a city and get the list of the cities plus the photos of that city, but I want that when they click that city, they should be able to see more information such as; names of the towns, and when they click any name of the town, it should bring them train times, buses times and taxis, which will further give the details of each.

```
-(void)dataRetrieveMethod
{
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:urlRetieval];
    NSData *data= [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:Nil];
    //instantiate arrays to hold data

    citiesArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i=0; i<json.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *ids = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSString *cityName = [[json objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"cityName"];



        City *myCity=[[City alloc] initWithCityID:ids CityName:cityName ];

        [citiesArray addObject:myCity];
    }

    [self.myTableView reloadData];


}
```

This gives me the list of  cities

how do i also store and retrieve the names of the town so that i can have something like this

LONDON  ------- [[Stratford] [.......trains
                           ......buses
                           ......taxi]]
        -------- [[Mile End] .......trains
                           ......buses
                           ......taxi]
        ---------[[Leyton]    .......trains
                           ......buses
                           ......taxi]
[image: picture here]

Comment: @martin R - code has been re-edited

Comment: What about using Core Data and something like RestKit?

Comment: why would someone vote this down without giving an explanation???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try it   use NSDictionary  under given  formate




      {
                milestones =             ( (2,3,4),(13,12));
                versions =             ((2,3,4),(13,12));
      },
  example
 NSArray *cities=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"trins",@"buss",@"taxi" ,nil];
    NSDictionary *towensdict=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:cities,@"stratford",cities,@"mile end",cities,@"leyton", nil];

    NSLog(@"cititedict:%@",towensdict);
    NSDictionary  *cities1=[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:towensdict,@"LONDON", nil];
    NSLog(@"cititedict:%@",cities1);
```

Comment: thanks for your comments. could you give me an example using City and Towns, I will figure out the rest. thanks

Comment: I tried your method but got this instead          Bath,
        Birmingham,
        London
    ) =     {
                (
            "Bath, Somerset",
            "Acock's Green",
            "Abbey Wood"
        ) =         (
                        (
                "taxi companies",
                "taxi companies",
                ""
            )
        );
    };
}

Comment: you are using key place also array that's way coming like that